# Replacing multiple lines of text using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file input.txt containing the following text

```
Total users:

    abc
    xyz
    pqrs
```

The number of users is subject to change but there will be atleast one user all the time. I want to replace the user names with wild card '*' using sed

```
Total users:

    *
```

Is there a way by which I can look for 'Total users:' string and replace everything after that with a *. Some thing like

```
sed s/Total users: \n[Till EOF]/Toal users: \n*/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
$ sed '3,$s/\S*$/*/' file
Total users:

    *
    *
    *
```

This does the substitution `s/\S*$/*/` from the third line in the file till the last line `3,$` where the substitution replaces any none whitespace characters till the end of line with a single `*`. Modified the substitution command as appropriate for your actual file as this will fail if you allow spaces in usernames. A more robust replacement might be:

```
$ sed -r '3,$s/(\s+).*/\1*/' file
Total users:

    *
    *
    *
```

This will replace after the initial whitespace with a single `*`. Use the `-i` option if you want to store the changes back to the file:

```
$ sed -ri '3,$s/(\s+).*/\1*/' file
```

**Edit:**

To replace all users with a single `*`:

```
$ sed -r '3{s/(\s+).*/\1*/;q}' file
Total users:

    *
```

Although creating this file would have been much quicker than asking a question.

Comment: The number of users is not fixed so there might be more than 3 users or less than 3 users so I guess it wont work

Comment: Like my answers explains, this does the substitution from the third line in the file until the last line. I works for a dynamic number of users.

Comment: I want any number of users being replaced with a single *

Comment: I have added a solution for that but why not just use a text editor?

Comment: the file is generated dynamically. I want to test it using automation. Thanks your solution worked

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need

```
sed -e "/Total users:/b; s|^\([[:blank:]]*\)[^[:blank:]]\+\(.*\)|\1*\2|" input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed -e '/^Total users:/ s/.*/&\n\n    */; q' input.txt
```

When it finds a line starting with `Total users:`, it replaces with itself, appends two line breaks and asterisk, and exits without processing any further lines.

If you are using a more limited version of `sed` where you cannot use `;` to separate multiple commands, you can write like this to work around:

```
sed -e '/^Total users:/ s/.*/&\n\n    */' -e '/^Total users:/ q' input.txt
```

Which is more verbose, but more portable.